# What book is Seren Koenig from?

Tags: story-identification, magic, dragons

I remember reading a book about Dragons who are babysitters of children. And one of them was forbidden to speak because the girl was mean to him. And they became bracelets

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Your question as it stands is a bit unclear; could you explain what it means for them to have 'become bracelets'?  Could you also add any more details e.g. is Seren Koenig a character, when did you read it etc?

Comment: Well. there's this Father Dragon who is the partner of Mr. Koenig who has three children, one of them is Seren. Then to protect them from danger the father dragon thing made his three children into bracelets so they could protect the guy's children. Something like that, because the Mother got kidnapped. idk.

Comment: All the details you can remember will help us out.  Thanks!

Comment: So, would u tell me what book it is? SOmething like Dragoslayer? or something like that?

Comment: Story identification isn't really my area of expertise sorry, I'm just trying to improve the quality of your question to improve the chances of it being answered

Comment: okay thanks. so, do you guys have a big Xanth fanbase here? CUz im a big fan and i dont seem to find anyone who i can chat with or exchange questions about it?

Comment: When you attain sufficient rep you'll be able to enter the chat rooms where you can discuss things like that at greater length; comments are supposed to focus on discussing the question itself.  I don't personally have experience with Xanth, but feel free to ask a question if you like!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Dragon's Game series by Carol Dennis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Game).

In the fourth book, [Dragon's Game](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Fg6Nd0VB5kgC), the dragon Soladon is transformed into a bracelet for Seren Koenig.

Comment: OMYGOD thank you. and i cant believe that one's the fourth book. i reemember now. there's a baby dragon and they hoard gold and he messed something up lol and there was the greek gods i think